# having an issue with a mongoose query involving .populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having an issue querying with mongoose.  First, my code:

Homework Schema:

```
var HomeworkSchema = new Schema({
    _class: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Class'
    },
    uncompleted:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
});
```

My query:

```
    Hw.find({_id:req.session.thisHomeworkId})
.populate("uncompleted")
.exec(function(err, docs) {
  console.log(docs)
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(err);
  } else {

    res.send(docs)
  }
})
```

If I take out the .populate, it return to me a array of objectIds.  If I leave it in, it returns a empty array with nothing in it.  The goal is to have it send me back the array with the user information instead of just the Ids.

Comment: How are you adding `User`s to the `uncompleted` property?

Comment: If the result is "empty" then that would suggest that the `ObjectId` values present in the array are not in fact found in the `User` model. Either you have an incorrect model name or the references are broken. The latter could be the case if you never "saved" the objects in the `User` model to begin with, and merely stored the `ObjectId` values in the `"uncompleted"` array of the `Homework` model.